# How to resolve license manager error -8 for R2015b matlab?

Tags: matlab

i am encountering the license manager error -8 for my MatLab R2015b. I did everything i can to resolve the error but did not succeed. How will it resolve?[That is the error i am encountering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bje7e.png)

Comment: You visited the mentioned website of course, what did it tell you?

Comment: It said that the Host ID specified in the license file must match the Host ID on the server line of the license file. but i did not find the server line in the license file. and my Host ID in the license file is "ANY"

Comment: here is the link to that troubleshooting site https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/100496-why-do-i-receive-license-manager-error-8

Comment: So you went through all those steps, otherwise you wouldn't be asking here. So the obvious follow-up question: what's your issue with those steps? Where does it go wrong for you? Please [edit] the post to be a lot more elaborate

Comment: Are you using a network license? Can you ping the server?

Comment: I did not find the server line. and that is my first time using MatLab. I don,t know how to ping MatLab server

Comment: if you are using matlab via your uni or workplace, contact your local support. if it is a personal copy, contact mathworks directly.

Answer (score 5):

I have found the solution for the error. Copy the files libmwservices.dll and Matlab_R2015b_glnxa64 from crack folder of the setup folder. And copy these two files in C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015b\bin\win32. This will resolve the problem.

Comment: I couldn't find the files you mentioned. Can you give me the link from where you downloaded Matlab?